# Non-default constructors for COM objects

Tags: visual-c++, object, com, constructor

How do you define a non-default constructor for a COM object in Visual C++?

Is such a thing even possible?

Or do you have to construct a default object and use an `init(params)` method to configure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COM coclasses implemented in C++ cannot have a constructor that takes an argument.  The CoCreateObject() function, the primary way to create an instance of a coclass, doesn't have any way to pass arguments.  Same with IClassFactory::CreateInstance(), the underlying method.

So yes, not possible, you'll need an Initialize() method.  And the code to verify that it was called, E_UNEXPECTED with a decent IErrorInfo message is boilerplate.