# Call non-default constructor of COM class

Tags: c#, vbscript, constructor, com, createobject

I have a DLL (written in C#) containing a class with 2 Constructors; a default (no arguments) constructor, and another one with 3 arguments.

In VBscript, I want to call the second constructor, but `CreateObject` only receives a `classValue` parameter, no possible `arguments` parameters.

I guess the underlying implementation of `CreateObject` uses the system's `CoCreateObject` function, which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8522970/1609201) does not support arguments, but on the other hand there's QTP/UFT's `DotNetFactory` that is capable of such thing, so there must be a way to do it in pure VBscript.

(I want to avoid the obvious `init` method solution if possible).

Any ideas for how to call my non-default constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COM does not support passing arguments to a constructor.  The underlying object factory method (IClassFactory::CreateInstance) does not accept arguments.

The workaround is pretty simple, all problems in software engineering can be solved by another level of indirection :)  Just create your own factory method.  You can write one that takes the arguments that the constructor needs.  Roughly:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IFoo {
   //...
}

class Foo : IFoo {
   public Foo(int a, string b) { ... }
   //...
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class FooFactory {
    public IFoo CreateInstance(int a, string b) {
        return new Foo(a, b);
    }
}
```

And your VBScript can now call FooFactory's CreateInstance() method to get your class object created.  Otherwise a very common pattern in COM object models, Microsoft Office automation is a very notable example.